# I have a set of random variables in matlab, with that how to find the discrete rv Z having pdf P(Z = 1) = p, P(Z = 0) = 1 – p, p = 0.3

Tags: matlab

n=1000
x=rand(n,1)

This is my code to find the random samples.

Comment: Please explain what 'discrete rv Z' is, and please explain all those properties that you want ('PDF P(Z=1)=p....') - I am a *mathematician* and I still have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: I want random sample values of random variable Z having pdf P(Z=1)=p,P(Z=0)=p-1, for p = 0.3

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's disambiguate what you want:

By "random sample values of random variable Z having pdf P(Z=1)=p,P(Z=0)=p-1, for p = 0.3" I assume you mean:

- You want to randomly choose between two values, `0` and `1`.
- `0` should occur 70% of the time.
- `1` should occur 30% of the time.

You already have the MATLAB statements:

```
n = 1000;
x = rand(n,1);
```

This is a good first step. The next step is for you read up on "logical indexing" in MATLAB, which is a way to apply a logical condition - say "is greater than 0.3" - to an array of numbers.

Try reading Peter Acklam's excellent reference ["MATLAB Tips and Tricks"](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/matlab/doc/mtt/doc/mtt.pdf), which will teach you about logical indexing and many other useful tricks for working with arrays in MATLAB.

---

As regards the phrasing of your question: There's no need to use overly technical language and abbreviations to describe a simple problem.

Also, to me, a PDF ("Probability Density Function") implies a continuous distribution like the normal distribution, which is why I was confused - you had the words "discrete" and "PDF" right next to each other, and it didn't compute. Again, don't use the technical jargon unless you actually have to.

Comment: Ok , Thank you for you adivce, The tips and tricks do not have info on pdf. Cna i know the code th the code to get the random variable for Z please

Comment: No, you may not have the code. I have given you the ingredients you need, a reference to read, and the name of the topic you need to read more about ("logical indexing".)  "pdf" is not mentioned because logical indexing is a tool for doing lots of things, not just sampling random numbers according to a probability density function.

Comment: is there a MATlab help online? cos I cant open my matlab now, i wnat to look at the logical indexing

Comment: Have you tried Googling "MATLAB Help", "MATLAB documentation" or "MATLAB Logical Indexing"? Please demonstrate that you're at least *trying* to solve your own problems before asking others.

Comment: I have tried all these and more but theya re not specifci enough, it is ok then , thank you I will jus keep looking

Comment: I have done the coding, can i know how to estimate the pdf of Z now?